# How to specific letter spacing in a sentence

Tags: html, css, letter-spacing

I have added `letter-spacing:-1px.` However I also need to `letter-spacing` the hiragana(japanese) numbers. I can't solve this problem by using romanji letter. 
How do I tighter(make less space) only for these number?

I tried to add `<span style>`between the sentence, but it did not do anything.

See my  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tokyo/e8vxm00n/#&togetherjs=GfxJGOtO7R)

```html
<div style="letter-spacing: -１px; font-weight: 500; text-transform: lowercase;"><strong>８４m<sup>2</sup> ~ ４５０m<sup>2</sup> 食事食事室</strong></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `span` for that, and avoid using inline styles:

#### Snippet

```css
div {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.has-letter-spacing{
  letter-spacing: -5px;
}
```

```html
<h3>HAS LETTER-SPACING IN SPAN</h3>
<div>
  <strong>８４m<sup>2</sup> ~ ４５０m<sup>2</sup> <span class="has-letter-spacing">食事食事室</span></strong>
</div>
<hr />
<h3>NO LETTER-SPACING IN SPAN</h3>
<div>
  <strong>８４m<sup>2</sup> ~ ４５０m<sup>2</sup> <span>食事食事室</span></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this did not work out. I tried your code in the fsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Tokyo/mxsp88to/3/

Comment: you did not use my code at all, there is no `span`, still inline styles, have you run my snippet?

Comment: sorry I gave the wrong link. Here is the correct link https://jsfiddle.net/Tokyo/mxsp88to/3/

Comment: Yes I run your snippet. and the space hasn't change. Strange that it does not work.

Comment: It is working, still I made two different  examples: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tdkyjL4a/) I updated my answer so you can run the snippet here and test it for yourself